# Swift: Issues with visual format language constraints

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am trying to set up a subview popup from my view controller and using visual format constraints to position the items. I want the subview to look like this with the tableView having a height of 150 pts, the imageView having a height of 100 pts and the titleLabel having a height of 50 pts and sitting in the bottom left of the imageView:

[image]

To try and achieve this I used the following code:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()

    // Add views
    addSubview(titleLabel)
    addSubview(tableView)
    addSubview(imageView)

    // Setup constraints
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
     let views: [String: UIView] = ["imageView": imageView, "titleLabel": titleLabel, "tableView": tableView]
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView(150)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[titleLabel][tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[titleLabel(20)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[imageView(100)][tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[imageView(100)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```

But this is resulting in the following output( the titleLabel is not showing):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with your constraints.  It is with the order of your views.  Add the `titleLabel` after the `imageView` to have it appear on top of the `imageView`:

```
// Add views
addSubview(tableView)
addSubview(imageView)
addSubview(titleLabel)
```

Since placement of your `titleLabel` is relative to your `imageView`, I would suggest making it a subview.  Here are the constraints I would suggest with comments:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()

    // Add views
    addSubview(tableView)
    addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.addSubview(titleLabel)

    // Setup constraints
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let views: [String: UIView] = ["imageView": imageView, "titleLabel": titleLabel, "tableView": tableView]

    // tableView is 150 wide and stuck to both sides of its superView making the superView 150 wide
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView(150)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    // imageView is 100 tall and stuck to top of superView; tableView takes up the rest
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[imageView(100)][tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    // imageView is as wide as its superView because it is stuck to both sides
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[imageView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    // titleLabel is 20 tall and stuck to the bottom of its superView (notice only one "|")
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[titleLabel(20)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    // titleLabel is 50 wide and stuck to the left of its superView (again only one "|")
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[titleLabel(50)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That has solved the issue of the tableView not appearing. The titleLabel is appearing in the centre of the imageView instead of at the bottom with the constraints I have posted in the question; any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: How about adding the titleView as a subview of the imageView?  Then you can constrain the titleView relative to its superView which will be the imageView.  Where do you want the title to appear? Centered horizontally and vertically in the imageView?

Comment: I want it to appear at the bottom left of the imageView (see first attached photo)

Comment: OK.  Got it.  And you want your label to be 20 tall and how wide?

Comment: Perhaps 50? It just has to be wide enough to fit a string of 20 letters.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for your help and time!

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for providing a detailed question with pictures.